# How to add two buttons on Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-pages

I'm unable to add two buttons at the same time to my Facebook page. In short, I want to go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [How To Add Two Call To Action Buttons To Facebook Page – OgbongeBlog](https://www.ogbongeblog.com/add-two-call-to-action-buttons-to-facebook-page.html), admins can’t see the two buttons but page visitors will see the two buttons. You need to sign out or click the 3 dots next to the `Share` button & click on `View as page visitor`.